# How is the correct way to use DialogFragment in MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-dialogfragment, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use DialogFragment in MVVM architecture but I cannot find the answers to some questions.

1. Should I use the @AndroidEntryPoint annotion? Like this:

   ```
   @AndroidEntryPoint
   class MyDialogFragment(): DialogFragment() {

   }
   ```
2. How should I provide the viewModel? Should DialogFragment have its own viewModel? Or is it better to use Fragment's viewModel? Like this:

   ```
   val viewModel: FragmentViewModel by viewModels()
   ```

   OR

   ```
   val viewModel: DialogFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
   ```
3. How should I communicate with the fragment I have called DialogFragment for?

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate the DialogFragment with @AndroidEntryPoint that way and don't forget to add `@Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle` in your viewModel constractor , the second question is personal preferences, some will use the main fragments ViewModel but if you plan on using the DialogFragment in multiple places you could have that have its own viewmodel, and as for communication you can pass data using events  you can have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents